# How to code in reactor to update a specific field in a cassandra DB record

Tags: java, spring-data, project-reactor

I am using ReactiveCassandraRepository and I can create new record as below.

```
public Mono<String> saveAbc(Abc toBeSaved) {
    return abcRepository.save(toBeSaved).map(saved -> saved.getId());
}
```

But I could not imagine how to update a specific field in a DB record since 2 reactive operations (findById & save) are involved.

I wrote a code as below to create or update status if exists, but seems to be not working.

```
public Mono<String> saveAbc(Abc toBeSaved) {
    return abcRepository.findById(toBeSaved.getId())
        .map(current -> abcRepository.save(transform(toBeSaved, current)).map(saved -> saved.getId()))
        .flatMap(id -> id);
}

private Abc transform(Abc toBeSaved, Abc current) {
    if(current == null) {
        return toBeSaved;
    } else {
        current.setStatus(toBeSaved.getStatus());
        return current;
    }
}
```

Can someone please assist on that?

Comment: How is this not working? Do you see error messages?

Comment: No any error logged, but object is not persisting in DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect your abcRepository's method to look something like this:

```
interface AbcRepository {
    Mono<Abc> findById(String id);

    Mono<Abc> save(Abc abc);
}
```

I guess from your code, for a given Abc you want to

1. read an Abc from repository with the same id,
2. map the data from the given Abc to the found one,
3. or just use the given Abc if the repository did not find any,
4. asynchronously save this Abc
5. and return the id of the saved element as Mono

I would do it like this:

```
public Mono<String> saveAbc(Abc toBeSaved) {
    return abcRepository.findById(toBeSaved.getId()) // (1)
            .map(abc -> transform(toBeSaved, abc))   // (2)
            .defaultIfEmpty(toBeSaved)               // (3)
            .flatMap(abcRepository::save)            // (4)
            .map(Abc::getId);                        // (5)
}

private Abc transform(Abc toBeSaved, Abc current) {
        current.setStatus(toBeSaved.getStatus());
        return current;
}
```

A Mono can only receive one or no element, so when using Mono:map (2) you don't need to handle null values. The Mono returned by the abcRepository will receive the found Abc in which case the transformation call (2) is done or it will just emit a complete signal in which case the map does nothing and defaultIfEmpty (3) emits toBeSaved as fallback.

If you have a transformation that is asynchronous itself and thus results in another Mono use flatMap (4), else your intermediate result would be an `Mono<Mono<Abc>>`.

And always remember: nothing happens until subscribe is called.

```
saveAbc(myNewAbc).subscribe(id -> System.out.println("Saved Abc with id: " + id));
```

---

In the above example I expected your repository to just emit a complete signal when findById doesn't find any matching Abc that will complete the Mono as empty (which is the case when using [ReactiveCassandraRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/reactive/ReactiveCrudRepository.html#findById-ID-)!). If instead the repository emits an exception in this case you can for example use

```
.onErrorResume(t -> Mono.just(toBeSaved))
```

instead of `defaultIfEmpty` (3).

Comment: Thank you very much MtTracer for your detailed answer. I will test and response again. But it takes few days.

Comment: This answer is correct and detailed Just note that in the context of Spring Framework, you'd just return the resulting `Mono` from the `@Controller`, since the framework takes care of subscribing for you.

Comment: Our problem was resolved with above answer, Thank you very much you ALL.

Comment: @SimonBaslé In the answer above,  transform method changes the state of a mutable object. Is that correct? should the object be immutable?

Comment: it could be dangerous to mutate eg the original parameter to the saveAbc method (since the repo might have returned a different more complete instance), but in the current case abc is returned by transform, ie the input to the map function. this is fine

Comment: @SimonBaslé thank you. This is not the case for me. I have created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67398326/reactor-update-objectss-state Could you please advise?