# Update objects's state in Reactor

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Given the following method:

```
private Mono<UserProfileUpdate> upsertUserIdentifier(UserProfileUpdate profileUpdate, String id){
    return userIdentifierRepository.findUserIdentifier(id)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
                profileUpdate.setNewUser(true);
                return createProfileIdentifier(profileUpdate.getType(), id);
            }))
            .map(userIdentifier -> {
                profileUpdate.setProfileId(userIdentifier.getProfileId());
                return profileUpdate;
            });
}
```

`switchIfEmpty` and `map` operators mutate the `profileUpdate` object. Is it safe to mutate in `switchIfEmpty` operator? Regarding `map`, if I have understood correctly, this is not safe and object `profileUpdate` must be immutable, right? eg:

```
private Mono<UserProfileUpdate> upsertUserIdentifier(UserProfileUpdate profileUpdate, String id){
        return userIdentifierRepository.findUserIdentifier(id)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
                    profileUpdate.setNewUser(true);
                    return createProfileIdentifier(profileUpdate.getType(), id);
                }))
                .map(userIdentifier -> profileUpdate.withProfileId(userIdentifier.getProfileId()));
    }
```

Later in the chain, another method mutates the object:

```
public Mono<UserProfileUpdate> transform(UserProfileUpdate profUpdate) {
        if (profUpdate.isNewUser()) {
            profUpdate.getAttributesToSet().putAll(profUpdate.getAttributesToSim());
        } else if (!profUpdate.getAttributesToSim().isEmpty()) {
            return  userProfileRepository.findUserProfileById(profUpdate.getProfileId())
                    .map(profile -> {
                        profUpdate.getAttributesToSet().putAll(
                                collectMissingAttributes(profUpdate.getAttributesToSim(), profile.getAttributes().keySet()));
                        return profUpdate;
                    });
        }
        return Mono.just(profUpdate);
    }
```

The above methods are called as follows:

```
  Mono.just(update)
  .flatMap(update -> upsertUserIdentifier(update, id))
  .flatMap(this::transform)
```

Comment: as pointed out in the answer below it depends. If your code example is safe. well sure. Does it make the code easy to follow. I would say no. It makes it hard to understand what state your object is in, and if done wrong somewhere the state could be mutated in a way that could lead to hard to find bugs and issues. I would avoid it, but thats me, and i would try to design everything with imutabillity in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nebulous answer, but... it depends!

The danger of mutating an input parameter in the returned `Mono` or `Flux` comes from the fact that said `Mono` or `Flux` could be subscribed multiple times. In such a case, suddenly you have a *shared resource* on your hands, and it can lead to puzzling issues.

But if the methods in question are called from a well controlled context, it can be safe.

In your case, `flatMap` ensures that the inner publishers are subscribed to only once. So as long as you *only* use these methods inside such flatMaps, they can safely mutate their input parameter (it is kept in the scope of the flatmapping function).

Answer (score 1):

There's arguably two factors here - the "dangerous" aspect and the "style" aspect.

Simon has covered the "dangerous" aspect very well; there is one thing I'd add however. Even though your code is "safe" within the method that we can see here (due to the guarantees we have behind a single subscription to an inner flatmap publisher), we still can't absolutely guarantee it's safe in a wider context - we don't know what else has visibility of, or might mutate, your `profileUpdate` parameter. If it's created, immediately passed into this method only, then read after this method completes, then sure, it's good. If it's created at some point in the past, perhaps passed around to a few methods that may or may not mutate it, passed back, passed into this method, passed into a few other methods... then, well, it *might* be safe, but it becomes increasingly difficult to analyse and say for certain - and if it's not safe, it becomes just as difficult to track down where that one in a million bug caused by the behaviour might occur.

Now, your code may look nothing like this complex mess I've just described - but with just a few lines changed here and there, or "just doing one more mutation" with this object elsewhere before it's passed in, it could start to get there.

That leads into the "style" aspect.

Personally, I'm very much a fan of keeping *everything* as part of the reactive chain where at all possible. Even ignoring the potential for bad mutations / side-effects, it becomes much harder to read the code if it's all written in this way - you have to mentally keep track of both the value being passed through the chain, as well as values external to the chain being mutated. With this example it's reasonably trivial, in larger examples it becomes almost unreadable (at least to my brain!)

So with that in mind, if I were reviewing this code I'd strongly prefer `UserProfileUpdate` to be immutable, then to use something like this instead:

```
private Mono<UserProfileUpdate> upsertUserIdentifier(UserProfileUpdate profileUpdate, String id){
    return userIdentifierRepository.findUserIdentifier(id)
            .switchIfEmpty(() -> createProfileIdentifier(profileUpdate.withNewUser(true), id))
            .map(userIdentifier -> profileUpdate.withProfileId(userIdentifier.getProfileId()));
}
```

...note this isn't a drop-in replacement, in particular:

- `createProfileIdentifier()` would just take a `UserProfileUpdate` object and an `id`, and be expected to return a new `UserProfileUpdate` object from those parameters;
- `UserProfileUpdate` would need to be enhanced with `@With` (lombok) or a similar implementation to allow it to produce immutable copies of itself with only a single value changed.
- Other code would likely need to be modified similarly to encapsulate the `profileUpdate` as part of the reactive chain, and not rely on mutating it.

However, in my opinion at least, the resulting code would be far more robust and readable.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. My `profileUpdate` instance holds some `Map`  references: `Map<ByteBuffer, byte[]> attributes`. Do you suggest to keep that map immutable as well?

Comment: @Lefteris Ideally yes - it should be immutable all the way down so you can guarantee you're not going to have nasty side-effects anywhere. Depending on the situation that may be more work than you're willing to give of course, I'm just painting the answer as an ideal perspective :-)